# Zend framework 2 - zftool.phar Windows 7 environment variable

Tags: php, zend-framework2, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to access the [zftool.phar](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool) (for Zend Framework 2) globally using an environment variable in Windows 7. I can't get it to work. Has anyone successfully achieved this?

Comment: Can you produce what you doing?

Comment: If you are setting the `$PATH` environment variable, then consider running the phar via absolute path until you got `$PATH` correctly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make folder C:\zftool
2. Download the "zftool.phar" from packages.zendframework.com(http://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar) into C:\zftool
3. Make "zftool.bat" file in C:\zftool with code:

   ```
   @echo off
   php %~dp0zftool.phar %*
   ```
4. Make "zftool" file(without extension) in C:\zftool with code:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   dir=$(d=$(dirname "$0"); cd "$d" && pwd)

   # see if we are running in cygwin by checking for cygpath program
   if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then

       # cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
       # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
       # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
       # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin.

       if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
           dir=$(cygpath -m $dir);
       fi
   fi

   dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
   php "${dir}/zftool.phar" $*
   ```
5. files in C:\zftool : 

   zftool

   zftool.bat

   zftool.phar
6. Add "C:\zftool" into PATH environment variable
7. Open CMD and type "`zftool`", check command "`zftool version`"
8. This allow you use in CMD short command "`zftool`" in any place without "`php zftool.phar`"
9. You have to run "`zftool`" command in the project folder to use in the current project

Answer (score 2):

Try to use command:

```
> php zftool.phar
```

But remember that before that path to the php.exe file must be added to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

or **create** and **run as administrator** "install-zftool.bat" file with code:

```
@echo off

::setting directory for installing zftool - change if necessary
set folder="C:\zftool"

::making directory
md "%folder%"

::downloading latest version of zftool.phar
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "ZFTool" "http://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar" "%folder%\zftool.phar"

::creating empty zftool and zftool.bat files
@echo. 2> %folder%\zftool
@echo. 2> %folder%\zftool.bat

::making zftool.bat file
@echo @echo off > %folder%\zftool.bat
@echo php %%~dp0zftool.phar %%*>> %folder%\zftool.bat

::making zftool file
@echo #!/bin/sh > %folder%\zftool
@echo dir=$(d=$(dirname "$0"); cd "$d" ^&^& pwd) >> %folder%\zftool
@echo if command -v 'cygpath' ^>/dev/null 2^>^&1; then >> %folder%\zftool
@echo if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then >> %folder%\zftool
@echo dir=$(cygpath -m $dir); >> %folder%\zftool
@echo fi>> %folder%\zftool
@echo fi>> %folder%\zftool
@echo dir=$(echo $dir ^| sed 's/ /\ /g')>> %folder%\zftool
@echo php "${dir}/zftool.phar" $*>> %folder%\zftool

::adding folder to PATH environment variable
setx path "%PATH%;%folder%" /M

exit
```

bat file will do all that is said above

do not forget **run as administrator**!

Comment: I'm always a little suspicious of answers witch insist on `run as administrator`.

Comment: @matsjoyce - without run as administrator you can't add folder to PATH environment variable.  you can comment `::setx path "%PATH%;%folder%" /M` and run as simple user, in that case you have to edit manually PATH variable...